# Sending information to API using Android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to contact an API and get the response. As part of my debugging I want to insure that the response is being recorded, it should be an xml response.

Here's what I have:

public class http extends Activity {

```
public void httpMethod(){
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://site.com/api/");

    try {
        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("apikey", "0d4e122d20"));

        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ip", "65.82.126.103"));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }

   TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
   myTextView.setText(response);
}
}
```

I'm trying to see the response that I get, however the variable response in the line

```
myTextView.setText(response)
```

is throwing an error:

```
response cannot be resolved to a variable
```

is response not truly a variable of the type httpresponse? what's going on here...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scope of the response variable is inside try block only. Two ways to resolve this:

1) Move these statements right after  `HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);`

```
 TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
   myTextView.setText(response);
```

2) Define `HttpResponse` response out side the try.

EDIT: As WindyB specified when you define outside the try block make sure `null` check to avoid `NullPointerException`.

Read this [link](http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html)

Comment: Or, to clarify even more: you should declare "HttpResponse response" outside your try block. Just be sure to perform a null check after your catch statement or your app may crash with a NullPointerException occasionally.

Comment: You've answered my official question and fixed my error. I can't believe I missed that... But I was hoping you might have an answer for me for this... Nothing is being displayed. It moves on to the next screen, but no response is given. Am I not using the functions properly? (I have allowed access to internet in the manifest)

Comment: and perhaps its something to do with fixing an error. it made me cast it to CharSeq to compile. so it looks like myTextView.setText((CharSeq) response);

Comment: You need to print stack trace. Add e.printStackTrac() inside both catch blocks. Second, log response status code using System.out. that may give some clues